# interact with file open window in headless chrome

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pyautogui

I've an application which I am automating using headless chrome using selenium python. One of the feature of this application is to upload files and send it into the application for processing.
For this there is a "Drag and Drop" button in the GUI which when clicked opens up the file "Open" window. From there I've to select the file and press "Open" button which will then be uploaded to the application.
I used AutoIT to send the file name in the File Open dialog box which works great.
When I try to use headless, it doesn't work.

I also tried pyautogui and this doesn't seem to work in headless mode as well (although I saw some notes that it can be used in headless browsers as well). I used the below commands in pyautogui to send file name in file open dialog window.

```
driver.get('URL')
myfile = "full path to myfile.pdf"
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'o')
pyautogui.PAUSE = 2
pyautogui.typewrite(myfile)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

When executing this opens the URL, but instead of sending the file name in file open dialog, it puts the file name in Pycharm editor. Not sure what mistake I am doing here.

Can pyautogui can be used in headless mode at all? If yes, can someone list the commands to enter file name in file open dialog window?

The same code works great without headless mode.

Thanks much.

Comment: Sorry, I was using a wrong Xpath it seems. The correct Xpath to the "Drag n Drop" button is element = "//div[@role='button']//input[@type='file']" This uploads the file when I used element.send_keys(filename) in non-headless mode. But in headless mode, it's not uploading and also not throwing any error. It just does nothing. Not sure what mistake I am doing here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can handle file uploading on its own, without any interaction with the window that pops up for humans.
Try to send keys to the upload element with the path to the file you wish to upload, like in this example:

find the upload element (will be different in your case)

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"]')
```

upload a file to it:

```
element.send_keys('C:/Path/to/your/file.pdf')
```

Comment: I tried your suggession, but still unable to upload the file. The application has a "Drag and Drop" button with XPATH as //div[@role='button' and @tabindex='0']. I used element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator)) where by_locator = the XPATH of the Drag button. Then I used element.send_keys(filename). I am not getting any error, but its not uploading also. When I send a click event on that button, it correctly opens up the file open Dialog window.

Comment: @Ram could you link the website/html you're trying to access?

Comment: It works good now. This is my internal company's web application. Thanks